# Picasa GData Scope

Tags: oauth, gdata, picasa

I'm having a problem authorizing my iOS application to access a user's Picasa photo albums. I'm using the Google Toolbox for Mac OAuth 2 Controllers and the GData Objective-C Client to access the Picasa API.

The Picasa Developer's Guide specifies the correct scope to use is:

> https://picasaweb.google.com/data/

But when using the scope above I'm getting this error message:

> objectFetcher:GTMHTTPFetcher 0x99ce930 (https://photos.googleapis.com/data/feed/api/user/someuser) failedWithStatus:403 data:Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope

What is the correct scope to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below as the scope, it works for me

```
https://photos.googleapis.com/data/
```

I found in

```
Source/Clients/Photos/GDataServiceGooglePhotos.m
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the following scope works for authentication (now when Picasa has retired):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos
```

It is, however, not listed in the 
[OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).
You will be asked to allow access to "manage photos and videos".